# Request.QueryString empty if 'Form' is one of the keys

Tags: asp.net, iis

The following query string results in Request.QueryString being empty:

http://intranetsite/form.apsx?InstanceID=123&Form=App.SomeForm

As soon as I change it to

http://intranetsite/form.apsx?InstanceID=123&Forms=App.SomeForm

`Request.QueryString` is populated with two key value pairs (InstanceID - 123 and Forms - App.SomeForm).

I am using IIS 8 on a win2k12 server. I *think* that this worked under IIS 7 but can't be sure. I have scoured the interweb for a list of key names that are blacklisted in `Request.QueryString` but no joy. Does anyone know of such a list and/or have a suggestion on why this is happening? My guess that it is because the key name is 'Form' could be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong diagnosis - QueryString was empty because the page was redirecting when `Form=<any value>` was in the URL. Thanks for everyone's help though!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVC or some other technique that applies routing to your URL?
It's just a long shot guess, but seing that your page name is also "form"(.aspx) it could be a routing issue...

EDIT: I have never heard of such a thing as blacklisted querystring parameter names. For sure certain characters won't work, but whole words - no, I've never encountered that.

Comment: It's not MVC but the form is called form.aspx so that might be it! I'll give it a try.

Comment: Any change when altering the name of the form?

Also, you might want to URL-encode your querystring parameters. Test if this problem remains of you remove the dot from "App.SomeForm". If the problem goes away when the dot is gone, URLEncoding will probably solve your issue.